# Psychic Mode for Empathy IM client

Tags: pidgin, empathy

The IM client [Pidgin](http://www.pidgin.im/) had a feature called "Psychic Mode", which showed which users started typing a message to me, even if I didn't received the first message yet.

Does anyone know if there is any plugin (or configuration I can change) in [Empathy](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy) with the same functionality?